# I keep getting unidentified varible $data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to create roles and permissions through spatie on this laravel project I'm working on. So far i believe I've done most of the things right but i keep getting unidentified variable $data when i call the index blade and i can't seem to find nor fix the problem.

Here is my index.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th width="280px">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @php
            $x = 1;
            @endphp
            @foreach ($data as $role)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $role->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $role->name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('roles.show',$role->id) }}">Show</a>
                    @can('role-edit')
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('roles.edit',$role->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    @endcan
                    @can('role-delete')
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['roles.destroy', $role->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    @endcan
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $data->render() }}
</div>
```

This is my controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = Role::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
    // return 100;

    return view('roles.index', compact('data'));
    
}
```

This is my route.

```
Route::get('/roles/index', function () {
return view('roles.index');})->middleware(['auth'])->name('roles.index');}
```

Comment: _"This is my route"_ - That route just returns the view without passing any data to it. That route won't call the controller you posted at all. It will use the anonymous function you passed in as the second argument as the controller. If you want to use that `index()`-method as your controller, you need to tell it to. I'd recommend you to  read through Laravel's documentation about routing: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass array containing controller class and action name as second parameter of `Route::get()` method

```
Route::get('/roles/index', [YourController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->name('roles.index');;
```